# How can I add school_id to my path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

in my search.html.haml, I want the user have the ability to click on the teacher name and it will lead them to the teacher show page. However, it also requires me to have the school_id because a teacher belongs to a school, and a school has many teachers. Now, I am wondering if there is a way for me to a the school_id to the path without breaking the application. The error that rails is throwing at me now is:

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"teachers", :id=>"1",
>   :school_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:school_id]

Here are my files:

**search.html.haml**:

```
.text-center
  / No search results announcement/notification
  - if @teachers.blank?
    %h2 Xin lỗi, hệ thống chúng tôi không có thông tin về giảng viên mà bạn muốn tìm.
  - else
    - @teachers.each do |teacher|
      %h2= link_to teacher.fullName, school_teacher_path(@school, teacher)
      #note
        %em
          Khoa #{teacher.department}, trường #{teacher.school.name}
```

**teachers_controller.rb**:

```
class TeachersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_school, except: [:welcome, :search]
  before_action :find_teacher, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def welcome
  end

  def show
  end

  def search
    if params[:search].present?
      @teachers = Teacher.search(params[:search], fields: [:fullName])
    else
      @teachers = nil
    end
  end

  def new
    @teacher = @school.teachers.build
  end

  def create
    @teacher = @school.teachers.create(teacher_params)
    @teacher.save
      redirect_to(@school)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @teacher.update(teacher_params)
    redirect_to(@school)
  end

  private

  def find_school
    @school = School.find(params[:school_id])
  end

  def find_teacher
    @teacher = Teacher.find(params[:id])
  end

  def teacher_params
    params.require(:teacher).permit(:firstName, :lastName, :middleName, :department, :school_id, :fullName)
  end
end
```

**teacher.rb**:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :ratings

  searchkick

  def name
    "#{lastName} #{middleName} #{firstName}"
  end

  def to_s
    name
  end
end
```

**school.rb**:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teachers, dependent: :destroy

  # searchkick
end
```

**routes.rb**:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  resources :schools do
    # collection do
    #   get 'search'
    # end
    resources :teachers do
      collection do
        get 'search'
      end
    end
  end

  resources :teachers do
    collection do
      get 'search'
    end
    resources :ratings
  end

  root 'teachers#welcome'
end
```

Comment: you can also access a *belongs to* relation in your case `teacher.school.id` will return the `id` of the `school` `teacher` belongs to...

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But could you show me more details? I dont quite get it.

Comment: see @froderik's answer..

Comment: @Minato yes, thanks a lot. I will try his solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`school_teacher_path` is called with a `@school` that is nil since `find_school` is not used for `search`. You probably want to replace `@school` with `teacher.school`: `school_teacher_path(teacher.school, teacher)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try your solution and let you know whether it can fix my current problem or not. Have a wonderful day.